# Not more than 20 markers displaying on Maps using Google maps Places library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Trying to fetch all the restaurants within a city using Google Places API. 
Even though there are 100 records returned, only 20 markers are displayed on map.
Below is the piece of code where we are creating markers. Please tell me if  I am missing something here. You may refer to below link and give input as restaurants in a 'Santa Clara' jsfiddle.net/r8g42046

//function used to create marker based on Location of a place.

```
  function createMarker(place){
    var place = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place         
        });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(place.name);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }

// Callback function based on results fetched from Places library based on type : restaurant.

 function callback(results, status, next_page_token) {
   if (results != null){
     resultlist.push(results);
    }
   if (next_page_token != undefined){
     textSearchrequest.pagetoken = next_page_token;
     service.textSearch(textSearchrequest,callback);
    }
   else{    
        findLocation(resultlist[0][0].place_id);
        for(var page = 0;page < resultlist.length;page++)
       {     
         for (var i = 0; i < resultlist[page].length; i++) {
         var place = resultlist[page][i]; 
         console.log(place.name); // Displays 100 restaurant names
         createMarker(place); //Call create marker function
        }
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  What is the query?  Are you using radarSearch, textSearch...?

Comment: You may refer to below link and give input as restaurants in a place http://jsfiddle.net/r8g42046/ . It returns 100 records but you can see only 20 markers displayed. Using TextSearch.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself**.

Comment: related question: [google maps radarSearch returning less than 200](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513810/google-maps-radarsearch-returning-less-than-200)

Comment: Note, textSearch is limited to 20 results.  Where do you see 100 records? [From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses): "By default, each place search returns up to 20 results per query. However, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages."

Comment: I have referred to next_page_token that indicates true/false/undefined based on the results in next page. Every page returns 20 records which I am pushing into an array. The length of array is 200. Guess its limited to 200 records.

Comment: This is limitation from Google as @geocodezip said. You will not be able to display more than 60 results if you use place search. I suggest you could add all place into your database and display result from that.

Comment: It is _supposed_ to be limited to 60. Note that scraping data from the Places API is prohibited by the terms of use, you can only permanently save the place_id.

Comment: Thank you, I am seeing 200 locations in result set. Its just with placing marker that I am facing problem with. Is there any limitation to that as well. I would be fine with displaying at least 60 markers. How can that be done ? Currently I see only 20 markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is completely useless:

```
 textSearchrequest.pagetoken = next_page_token;
```

`pagetoken` is a URL-parameter for the places-webservice and has no meaning in the places-library

it will not lead you to the next page of results.

You always get the same set of(20) results and draw the same set of markers again and again, until you hit the QUERY_LIMIT. When you hit the QUERY_LIMIT after 10 requests, you draw 200, when you hit it after 12 request 240, but no matter how often you may run the search, you never get more than 20 different places(markers)

Although you draw 200 (or more)markers you only see 20 markers, because they are at the same locations.

Use the method [pagination.nextPage()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#PlaceSearchPaging) to access the next set of results.

Comment: You were right. I had not observed that the result-set was repeating. Finally I was able to get it to work using pagination.nextPage(). I don't have enough reputation to upvote this answer yet, but definitely this answers deserves one. Thank you very much.